# script php rodando como sudo

Tags: php, linux

Já criei um *script* PHP que me cria uma pasta dentro do meu diretório `home` do Linux, porém quero saber agora como mudar seus direitos (`rwx`) pois a pasta criada tem como proprietário o *daemon* e o restante do *script* (`chown`) não funciona.Por favor, detalhem, pois não tenho muita experiência com o Linux.

Comment: O que tentou fazer? Qual erro deu? Se colocar essa parte do script fica mais fácil alguém te ajudar.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois está ampla demais a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Você deve explicar se está rodando seu PHP no terminal ou no webserver

Answer (score 1):

1º - **Não te recomendo a executar scripts pelo php com o sudo, pois como você mesmo disse não tem muito conhecimento em linux, e isso seria uma grande brecha não só em sua aplicação mais em todo o seu S.O.**.

2º - Você poderia criar uma pasta com permissão global para que todos à acessem, assim acredito que funcionária para você mkdir("nome_diretorio", *0777*);

*Mais informações sobre permissões no linux no link abaixo*

http://www.infowester.com/linuxpermissoes.php

3º - Você pode executar qualquer comando no sistema operacional com o **exec ou shell_exec**

Mais alguns dados sobre permissões abaixo:

---------   000

r--------   400

r--r--r--   444

rw-------   600

rw-r--r--   644

rw-rw-rw-   666

rwx------   700

rwxr-x---   750

rwxr-xr-x   755

rwxrwxrwx   777

Answer (score 0):

Você já pode criar a pasta com permissões para todos acessarem:

```
mkdir("pasta", 0777);
```

Para executar qualquer comando do linux no PHP como admin, você deve criar um arquivo com a senha do root e passá-lo para o sudo. Assumindo que você tenha salvo esse arquivo no "/var/www/meuprojeto", com o nome de "senha.secret":

```
exec('sudo -u root -S chown "usuario" "pasta" < /var/www/meuprojeto/senha.secret');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Crie seu script PHP sem importar-se com o usuário que executará, usando `chmod` para alterar as permissões de diretórios.
2. Execute seu script via linha de comando:
   `sudo php meuscript.php`

Existem muitos "**poréns**" no uso desta abordagem, mas se você é o root e quer uma script para lhe ajudar a administrar o sistema, OK!

Entretando, possivelmente `bash` será a melhor linguagem para atingir seu objetivo.

Comment: Com o apoio do pessoal aqui do forum e mais algumas pesquisas consegui notar o erro que estava comentendo e resolvi os problemas até aqui, digo isso pois o projeto continua e talvês venha a ter novas dúvidas. Só para constar  encontrei no Yast o edtor do Sudoers e consegui inserir as linhas que davam permissão para o script do php rodar sem pedir senha e com direitos de sudo, alem é claro de escrever estas linhas de forma correta no php. Grato a todos.

Comment: Algumas destas respostas foi a que mais lhe ajudou? Marque-a como resposta aceita.